# Why my photos are missing in iPhoto events but not in Aperture projects?

Tags: photos.app, aperture

All my iPhoto events are empty. If I open a event there are no photos in it. But when I use the *Photos* perspective I can see all my photos!

In Aperture I see all my photos in the *Photos* perspective and in projects (= iPhoto events).

How I can repair my iPhoto library?

I already tried to repair and rebuild my hole library with iPhoto an Aperture!

Comment: Is anything not understandable? I know that my English is not the best. Please leave a comment if anything not good described!

Comment: Photos marked as rejected in Aperture don't show in iPhoto... is it possible this is the case here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [iPhoto Library Manager](http://www.fatcatsoftware.com/iplm/) and use its rebuild function. (In Library Manager it's the FIle -> Rebuild command)

This will create an entirely new library. It will then copy (or try to) your photos and all the associated metadata and versions to this new Library, and arrange it as close as it can to what you had in the damaged Library. It does this based on information it finds in the iPhoto sharing mechanism - but that means that things not shared won't be there, so no slideshows, books or calendars, for instance - but it should get all your events, albums and keywords, faces and places back.

Because this process creates an entirely new library and leaves your old one untouched, it is non-destructive, and if you're not happy with the results you can simply return to your old one.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. You must work very careful with the iPhoto Library Manager. In my case it ignores 12 events with about 1000 photos. I rescued them manually. But now I have a valid iPhoto library and the events contains the photos!!!